# Как отправлять запросы в Azure service на клиент?

Tags: c#, azure, веб-служба

Нужно написать сервис который будет парсить данные с сайта и отправлять их на клиент(мобильный или desktop). Подскажите как это работает.

Comment: Что именно вы понимаете под Azure Service? Web App, Service Fabric, Service bus, ...?

Comment: Мне нужно создать Web App по MVC модели

Comment: Ну пишется он точно так же. Разницы никакой нет. Только вот задеплоить можно разыми методами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web App - это просто обычный вебсайт, к нему подходят все те же методы работы что и с обычным вебсайтом.

Способы отсылки данных на клиет:

1. Пулинг. Клиент периодически дергает сервер по http запросу и сервер либо отдает данные либо отдает ответ что ничего нет. В обработчике запроса можете парсить сайт, кешировать и всё такое. Плюс: никаких лишних библиотек, простая реализация.
2. Дуплексная комуникация - установка канала связи для моментальной передачи данных. В случае C# на сервере и клиенте - рекомендую [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). Плюс: возможность коммуникации в реальном времени, большая гибкость стандартных настроек.

Для второго метода не забудьте включить WebSockets в настройках приложения в ажуре. SignalR будет работать и без них, только хуже.